# Kotlin classes containing android-extensions not built on consequent builds

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have recently decided to port our company android application into kotlin. It works well, however, when I use any of the kotlin extensions, I get a weird behaviour. I noticed that any of the classes using extensions (be it anko, or self declared extensions) is only build the first time, and on each subsequent build it is not present among other classes. Kotlin classes that do not use extensions are built correctly all the time. 
This leads to a NoClassDefFoundError whenever I run the program (on subsequent builds, the first one runs without issues).
I have tried everything and I am starting to get a bit desperate…
Here is my build.gradle for the whole project:

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1-2'
    ext.support_version = '23.3.0'
    ext.anko_version = '0.8.3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.7'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
}
```

Here is build.gradle for the module that I am attempting to use kotlin in

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
        }
        maven {
            url "http://repo.bodar.com/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            minSdkVersion 19
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resValue "string", "tray__authority", "${applicationId}.tray"
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    retrolambda {
        jvmArgs '-noverify'
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo.bodar.com/"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://clojars.org/repo/"
    }
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"
    androidTestCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.2:grooid'
    androidTestCompile 'com.andrewreitz:spock-android:1.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
        exclude group: 'junit'
    }
    // Optional, needed for mocking
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'

    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/guava-18.0.jar')
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.4'
    compile files('libs/icepick-2.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/icepick-processor-2.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar')
    compile project(':fliclib')
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:0.9.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core-slh:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.totallylazy:totallylazy:1.73'
    compile 'net.grandcentrix.tray:tray:0.9.2'
    compile 'org.solovyev.android.views:linear-layout-manager:0.5@aar'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.traex.expandablelayout:library:1.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the manifest for that module (or rather it's heading as the code is propietary)

```
<manifest package="com.package.name"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:versionCode="23"
          android:versionName="0.9.1">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to figure it out, maybe it will help someone else. Apparently the problem was with java annotations (`@DebugLog, @NonNull, @Icicle` etc.), if they were present in any of the kotlin classes, it would compile semi-randomly. After removing thoses it works flawlessly.

Comment: I see you are using the test coverage flag - there seems to be a bug there that might be causing a lot of weird behaviour :) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11333